# Searching in typeahead if content matches

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typeahead.js

I have a typeahead.js search that searches two different categories (applications and contacts) each calling the backend for json files. I am adding the ability to search by app and contact ID and would like to stop the other from triggering if the first three characters are "OA-" or "OC-" respectively.

```
searchTerms.typeahead {
  hint: true
  highlight: true
  minLength: 3
}, {
  name: 'applications'
  displayKey: 'address'
  valueKey: 'id'
  source: searchApplications.ttAdapter()
  templates:
    header: '<h4 class="tt-header">Applications:</h34>',
    suggestion: (data) ->
      if data.external_code
        '<div class="search-result-item">' + data.address + ' – ' + data.external_code + '</div>'
      else
        '<div class="search-result-item">' + data.address + ' <span class="btn btn-sm btn-id">OA-' + data.id + '</span></div>'
  limit: 10
},
name: 'contacts'
displayKey: 'name'
valueKey: 'id'
source: searchContacts.ttAdapter()
templates: header: '<h4 class="tt-header">Contacts:</h4>',
suggestion: (data) ->
  '<div class="">' + data.name + ' <span class="btn btn-sm btn-id">OC-' + data.id + '</span></div>'
limit: 10
```

How can I stop the second from running if the fisrt 3 characters are "OA-" or "OC-"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out eventually...

The solution requires the modification in Bloodhound which the `source: searchApplications.ttAdapter()` uses.

In the `new Bloodhound` function, I used prepare to run a beforeSend action:

```
search = new Bloodhound(
    remote:
      url: '/applications.json'
      prepare: (query, settings) ->
        settings.url = settings.url + '?query=' + query + '&search=true'
        settings.beforeSend = (e) ->
          if query.substr(0,3).toLowerCase() == 'oc-'
            e.abort()
        return settings
)
```